# django-imagekit - thumbnail field not getting serialized

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-imagekit

I have following problem:

I'm writing an AJAX view in django that serves JSON data about image list from a model that uses `ImageSpecField` from django-imagekit extension:

```
class Image(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   img = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
   thumb = ImageSpecField(source="img",
       id="core:image:image_thumbnail"
     )
   objects = models.Manager()
   json_data = JSONConvertibleManager()
```

The model uses custom manager for conversion into JSON (`JSONConvertibleManager`) using built-in Django serializer (instance of `django.core.serializers`).

My problem is that all the fields are properly serialized except for the `ImageSpecField` which is getting completely ommited. Is it possible to return `instance.thumb.url` value during serialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for info I was using Django Rest Framework and so used the serializer class from that library.

My model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    """ Photograph """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='boxes')
    formatted_image = ImageSpecField(source='original_image', format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 90})
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField([Adjust(contrast=1.2, sharpness=1.1),
        ResizeToFill(200, 115)], source='original_image',
        format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90})
    num_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
```

My serializer:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    original_image = serializers.Field('original_image.url')
    thumbnail = serializers.Field('thumbnail.url')

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'original_image', 'thumbnail',)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer does not work anymore due to changes in DRF (prob. v2.x). Substitute this line and it will work with current versions (3.5.3):

```
thumbnail = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="thumbnail.url")
```

Another solution to have more control (e.g. url modifications) would be:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    original_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'original_image')

    def get_original_image(self, obj):
        # some processing
        return obj.original_image.url
```

Comment: This should selected as answer.

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement based on the nice solution given by @Insa ...

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    original_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'original_image')

    def get_original_image(self, obj):
        if bool(obj.original_image):
            return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(obj.original_image.url)
        return ''
```

to obtain the absolute url for the thumbnail, as happens by default for all ImageFields